# Crash Report not receiving in Flurry (Swift, iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, flurry, flurry-analytics

Events, sessions and other functionality is working perfectly fine but when it comes to crash reporting it sucks. No crash report is generating. I have used the following code :-

```
Flurry.startSession("2XKDMH8M7PQM75B7SKZR")
        Flurry.setCrashReportingEnabled(true)
        Flurry.setSessionReportsOnCloseEnabled(true);
        Flurry.setSessionReportsOnPauseEnabled(true);
        Flurry.logPageView()

        let locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager();
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation();
```

Comment: check this URL: https://dev.flurry.com/developer/crash/1300
And click Single App Overview

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should place the configuration details before the call to startSession. For crash reporting this is required.

Please change your code to:

```
    Flurry.setCrashReportingEnabled(true);
    Flurry.setSessionReportsOnCloseEnabled(true);
    Flurry.setSessionReportsOnPauseEnabled(true);
    Flurry.logPageView();

Flurry.startSession("2XKDMH8M7PQM75B7SKZR")


    let locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager();
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation();
```

Comment: I also tried whatever you have said, but still it is not working